# USB Devices with VMWare

Tags: vmware

Normally when you connect a USB device while VMWare is running, it will prompt you if you want to connect it to guest or host. It also has a small checkbox that says "remember this setting" so it doesn't prompt you again. Someone recently checked this checkbox and selected host, but I need it shared on the guest. How do I re-enable this dialog box or change the default behavior for the USB device?

I am currently using VMWare Workstation Player 15.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the solution to reset this dialog box, but I found a work-around to auto connect the USB device to the virtual machine.

You need to edit the .vmx file under C:\Users\&USERNAME&\Virtual
Machines\&VIRTUALMACHINENAME&\

I would recommend making a copy of this file just in case something breaks.
Add the following line to the bottom of the file:

```
usb.autoConnect.device0 = "vid:0x0123 pid:0xabcd autoclean:1"
```

You will need to replace the vid and pid for the device you are wanting to auto connect. You can find this under the device manager, right click on the device and go to Properties. Then go to Details. Scroll through the different properties until you see the VID or PID. It's normally under "Device Instance Path" or "Parent".